# Google Analytics and Yii2 pages requiring login

Tags: php, authentication, google-analytics, yii2

I am designing a website using Yii2 framework and want to include a Google Analytics tracking code. I guess the best place to include it such that it gets generated in all the is the main.php layout file.

My concern is what will happen if it gets generated in a page that requires a user to log in and may contain data confidential to them. Does it matter, since it is not search indexing, or is there any other check for authorized pages that I should do before generating the script? How?

Regards,

Shahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have one or more controllers to process and show all protected pages and have the following code in main.php.

```
<?php 
    $gaBlackList = ['protected'];
    if (!in_array(Yii::$app->controller->id, $gaBlackList)) {
        include_once('/config/tracking.php');
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case you just need to check it in your `layout` may be `main.php` in your case if user is authenticated or not using this.
if you are setting username for login

```
$privateUrl = ['user/create','user/view'];
$currentUrl = Yii::$app->controller->id . '/' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
if (in_array($currentUrl, $privateUrl)) {
    if (Yii::$app->user->identity->username) {
    // GA for authenticated users only
    }
} else {
    // GA for guest
}
```

Comment: That was my original thought, but it will not work. There are pages that a logged in user can see that are public and can be tracked. I need to run a condition on the page, not the user. Either, I need to figure out a way to set a flag in pages that can be tracked or not, or don't bother, if GA will not store confidential info.

Comment: Hi yiiframe. Thanks for your inputs. As mentioned earlier, the user having logged in or not does not matter as much as whether the page is protected. I have a solution though and thank you for helping me get there.